# Hibernate: performing a very complex selection/filtering. Is pagination a good option?

Tags: hibernate, pagination

I have to find items that are in a database. First I use a database query which is followed by a filter. This filter, which is far too complex to be rewritten as a database query, removes items from the list that do not match the filter.

We use Hibernate with a large database.

So how can I process the two-step process without having too much impact on the production performance?

My thought was using Hibernate pagination. So, retrieve 100 objects from the database, apply the filter, till a threshold number of say 200 is reached. Then the result can be returned for further processing.

Using Hibernate pagination: How can I retrieve a series of pages of (e.g. 30) items? Assume that it (really) not possible to transform the filter to a database query.

The high-level approach is:

```
WHILE not enough items found DO
  find the next page/series of items
  apply a filter on the found items to remove invalid ones
  IF enough items found STOP
DONE
```

For finding the next page/batch/series of items I see a lot of answers like:

```
public List<T> getItems( Session session, int pageSize, int currentPage) {
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Item.class);
    criteria.setFirstResult( calculateOffset( currentPage); 
    criteria.setMaxResults( pageSize);
    return criteria.list();
}
private int calculateOffset(int currentPage, int pageSize) {
    return ((pageSize * currentPage) - pageSize);
}
```

Yes, it is not possible to convert the 'filter' into a database search criterium. Requesting all objects from the database has too much impact on the database performance for (other) production users.

Below you find an example implementation how I did it thus far. It is far too slow. 
Are there faster & better ways to scroll / paginate through the database?

```
// The production database should not be queried too heavily
List<Item> endresult = new ArrayList<Item>();
// Building a complex db query
Criteria searchCriteria = buildFindAanleveringForCriteria( criteria); 
int startSearchingAt = 0;
int searchLimit = criteria.getMaxResults();
int currentPage = 0;
searchCriteria.setFirstResult( startSearchingAt);
searchCriteria.setMaxResults( searchLimit);
while( ! searchLimitIsReached) {
    List<Item> queryResult = searchCriteria.list();
    if( queryResult == null || queryResult.isEmpty()) {
        searchLimitIsReached = true; // no more data available
    }
    // all kinds of processing goes here
    // applying a very complex filter on the list to remove invalid items
    //   the filter cannot be used in a query to the database
    endresult.addAll( filterOnStatus( queryResult, criteria.getStatus()));
    // Stop if no filtering was done on the aanleverstatus. Wachten status are only near THIS (now) moment
if ( aanleveringen.size() >= criteria.getMaxResults()) {
        searchLimitIsReached = true; // no further search is needed.
    }
    // Where to start the next page of results
    startSearchingAt = (++currentPage * searchLimit);
    searchCriteria.setFirstResult( startSearchingAt);
}
```

Comment: This is too abstract to comment as filtering and pagination are supported by both Hibernate and JPA, both of which are tagged on the question. Perhaps a concrete case would help provide inputs. Also, the question is tagged with `spring-data-jpa` but refers exclusively to native Hibernate code. Is the solution desired to be with Hibernate or Spring Data JPA?

Comment: @manish - I have to work with code like given in the question. I removed the JPA.

Comment: Without seeing the code that will filter the objects, it is impossible to say if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, how can we find a solution with (very) complex selecting/filtering logic that performs good enough?

**Option 1**: Spring/hibernate pagination - see the solution above. A search screen took about 400 seconds to build up.

**Option 2**: Hibernate/Scrollable result. As [Baeldung describes this solution](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-pagination):

```
String hql = "FROM Foo f order by f.name";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
int pageSize = 10;     
ScrollableResults resultScroll = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
resultScroll.first();
resultScroll.scroll(0);
List<Foo> fooPage = Lists.newArrayList();
int i = 0;
while (pageSize > i++) {
    fooPage.add((Foo) resultScroll.get(0));
    if (!resultScroll.next())
        break;
}
```

It took over 400 seconds to build the results.

**Solution 3**: We built a stored procedure, so putting logic in the database. Many architect's would like to concentrate the logic in 1 place, mostly not in a database. We built this option just to see whether this solution would be lot more performant. 
The solution of calling a stored procedure from hibernate is described via [Baeldung in this document](http://www.baeldung.com/stored-procedures-with-hibernate-tutorial) and it took about 10 seconds to complete. 
So, we put all logic of this specific query & filter in 1 place ... in the database.

**Option 4**: SQL statement embedded in Java? This would be too complex a logic to put into an SQL query.